# Wrong Braces Layout after "Move To Another File"

Tags: c#, resharper

When using the Refactoring Tool `Move To Another File` or `Move Types Into Matching Files` Resharper uses the wrong line break style after the namespace. If I refactor a class with these tools it generates code like so, although my `Braces Layout` is configured with *At next line (BSD style)*

```
namespace My.Namespace { // <- This brace should be on the next line
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass() 
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm doing a *Code Cleanup* afterwards, the code gets formatted correctly:

```
namespace My.Namespace 
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass() 
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone know what might cause this behaviour? Why isn't there a line break before the namespace's brace in the first place?

I'm using ReSharper 2018.3.1

Comment: Are you saying you use ReSharper to both cause (via one command) and later fix (via a different command) the problem?

Comment: How are you doing `Code Cleanup`?

Comment: Yes, both commands are ReSharper commands. Resetting all Settings to default fixes the problem, but I'd rather not lose all my settings.

Comment: @RandRandom ReSharper > Edit > Code Cleanup

Comment: To bad thought maybe you use Visual Studio's `Code Cleanup` which may have different settings

Comment: @Winetradr if you say that resetting the setting to default fixes the problem, then the issue lays somewhere in your settings I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my problem:

`ReSharper > Options > Code Editing > c# > Formatting Style > Braces Layout`

The Setting `Empty braces formatting` was on `Together on the same line`. So I changed that to `On different lines`. After this change it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is setting for braces on
`ReSharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Braces Layout`

Can you check `Type and namespace declaration` setting is set for *`At Next Line (BSD Style)`*

I am using ReSharper 2018.2.3 and everything works perfectly.

#### Update

I updated my ReSharper to 18.3.1 and still everything is OK. Can you also check for VS default options for braces on `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines > New line options for braces`.

I am afraid ReSharper can not overriden all Visual Stuido behaviours. In order to avoid this, just turn off all 'Automatically
format ...' options on `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > General`, so that it doesn't get in the way.

Comment: Thanks, turns out it had to do with the setting `Empty braces formatting`